Is it legal to reverse engineer source from an Apache-2.0 licensed binary, and redistribute that source?
I've recently discovered a tool that is distributed binary-only under the Apache-2.0 license. The authors are clear and explicit that the tool is not "open source" (there is no source code available), but appear to be encouraging free use of the binaries.
Which got me thinking - if someone were to reverse engineer hi-fidelity source code from those binaries†, would they be able to redistribute that reverse engineered source code under Apache-2.0, provided they met all the requirements of section 4 when distributing that source code?

†I realise that's a big "if" - for the sake of my question please assume high quality reverse engineering is feasible.

‡Please also ignore the probable social backlash such an activity might trigger from the authors. I'm well aware this is almost certainly antagonistic, but am only interested in the legalities.

Are you sure the binary you received is "only" covered by Apache-2.0? Note that Apache-2.0 Section 2 allows sublicensing (i.e. additional terms might have been added to the binary that you downloaded). Additional non-Apache-2.0 code might also have been added to the binary, which is allowed by the Apache License but that license doesn't give you permission to make derivatives of the non-Apahce portions (assuming you can identify which is which).

Coudl you provide a link to the page or product in question.

@Brandin the binary does include 3rd party open source libraries, under a variety of licenses, and those appear to be correctly identified.  The source code for those libraries is available elsewhere, and my question doesn't relate to those libraries.

It's worth mentioning that the authors (or you, not sure if you're quoting them) are not using the common usage of the term "open source". They've released the software under an open source license.

@CaptainMan hard agree. Hence my question, which could be rephrased more emotively as "would it be legal for someone to attempt to liberate the source code from this abomination"  ;-)

Reverse engineering non-open source
Completely apart from whether the binary is open source software are not, you may want to look into the legality of reverse engineering non-open source software. (If it's legal to reverse engineer non-open source software, surely it's legal to reverse engineer open source software.) Here is an article and an archived copy. I don't know enough about the topic to comment on the legality (and obviously I am not a lawyer), but it seems like there are ways this could be done legally even if the binary was not licensed under an open source license.
Derivative works based on Apache licensed code
Regardless, the binary is licensed under an open source license.
In the Apache License, Version 2.0 in section 2 it says you are allowed to prepare Derivative Works and distribute them in Source or Object form so long as you meet the conditions in section 4.

1. Definitions.
[...]
"Source" form shall mean the preferred form for making modifications, including but not limited to software source code, documentation source, and configuration files.
"Object" form shall mean any form resulting from mechanical transformation or translation of a Source form, including but not limited to compiled object code, generated documentation, and conversions to other media types.
"Work" shall mean the work of authorship, whether in Source or Object form, made available under the License, as indicated by a copyright notice that is included in or attached to the work (an example is provided in the Appendix below).
"Derivative Works" shall mean any work, whether in Source or Object form, that is based on (or derived from) the Work and for which the editorial revisions, annotations, elaborations, or other modifications represent, as a whole, an original work of authorship. For the purposes of this License, Derivative Works shall not include works that remain separable from, or merely link (or bind by name) to the interfaces of, the Work and Derivative Works thereof.
[...]
2. Grant of Copyright License. Subject to the terms and conditions of this License, each Contributor hereby grants to You a perpetual, worldwide, non-exclusive, no-charge, royalty-free, irrevocable copyright license to reproduce, prepare Derivative Works of, publicly display, publicly perform, sublicense, and distribute the Work and such Derivative Works in Source or Object form.
[...]
4. Redistribution. You may reproduce and distribute copies of the Work or Derivative Works thereof in any medium, with or without modifications, and in Source or Object form, provided that You meet the following conditions: [see full document for restrictions]

Based on the definitions, what you're asking about is creating a Derivative Work in Source form. So, like you said, as long as you meet the requirements in section 4 then I believe you'd be fine. Also, you should be fine in the event that they come after you for patent infringement since Apache covers that in section 3.
Caveats

Be wary of trademarks. You'll probably need to call your new library something else.
Before putting significant work into this it may be worthwhile to consult an actual lawyer. I'd hate for you to devote months to this only to get hit with a lawsuit or something.


Thanks. Yeah that pretty much echoes my reading of the license too, but I'm really looking for a legal expert's reading, as "plain text" readings of licenses can sometimes get one into trouble. And note that section 6 of the ASL makes downstream's trademark rights explicit (i.e. there are none - downstream users CANNOT use trademarks themselves).

@Peter it may be worth asking law SE. It has to be a general question and not one specific to you though. Either way, rewriting the entirety of source code for some Apache licensed project would be permitted if the source code were released, I don't show how it not being released changes that.
